# warning: comparison between 'enum sf::Keyboard::Key' and 'enum sf::Mouse::Button' [-Wenum-compare]|

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using the [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) libraby in C++  graphics for my chess game.

There's a Left-Click Mouse event that happens when you move the pieces in the game. So here's how I originally track that.

```cpp
sf::Event e;
if (e.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased){
    if(e.key.code == sf::Mouse::Left){
     //Do something
    }
}
```

This gives the following compilation **Warning**;

```cpp
|1175|warning: comparison between 'enum sf::Keyboard::Key' and 'enum sf::Mouse::Button' [-Wenum-compare]|
```

The code will still execute properly.

- Why does this problem occur?
- What is the solution to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member `key` in `sf::Event` (i.e., `sf::Event::key`) is an enumerator from the enumeration `sf::Keyboard::Key`, whereas the enumerator `sf::Mouse::Left` belongs to the enumeration `sf::Mouse::Button`.

In principle, you should only be interested in the `key` member of the union in `sf::Event` when handling the event `sf::Event::KeyPressed` or `sf::Event::KeyReleased`.

As you are handling the event `sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased`, the wrong data member (`sf::Event::key`) in the union is being compared against the enumerator `sf::Mouse::Left`. Try instead comparing against `e.mouseButton.button`:

```
sf::Event e;
if (e.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased){
    if (e.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left){
     //Do something
    }
```

Comment: How can this answer be any better :), It feels so good to see this now :))

Comment: ||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|